# Order by upcoming months in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to order the set of records by month in laravel 5.
The problem is when I use `order by 'Month'`, it just ordered the records by alphabets like

`apr, aug, dec, feb, jan, jul, jun, may..`.

But what I want is something like this:

`jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug`

It should order by upcoming months.

Here is my code:

```
public static function getMonths($customer_id = false)
{   
    $customer = DB::table('customer');
    $customer->join('customer_month_calender','customer_month_calender.customer_id','=','customer.id','left');
    $customer->select('customer.id','customer.name','customer_month_calender.month');
    $customer->orderBy(DB::raw('MONTHNAME(customer_month_calender.month)'), 'asc');
    $customer->groupBy('customer.id');
    return $customer->get();
}
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

I think it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
TRY this it will work
public static function getMonths($customer_id = false)
{   
$customer = DB::table('customer');
$customer->join('customer_month_calender','customer_month_calender.customer_id','=','customer.id','left');
$customer->select('customer.id','customer.name','customer_month_calender.month');
$customer->orderBy(DB::raw('MONTH(customer_month_calender.month)'), 'asc');
$customer->groupBy('customer.id');
return $customer->get();
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your code?